# Create one decimal only in specific area

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, mdx

Goal:
Make the column [Internet Average Unit Price], [Internet Sales Amount] and [Internet Total Product Cost] with Arizona area to have one decimal only. The remaining numbers in different City, State province to have non decimal value.

Problem:
I tried finding a solution for it but I failed.

Information:
*Using AdventureWorks DW 2012 multidimensional
*The datasource is SSAS.
*The list in the picture is not before affected in format. In other words, it is raw data from SSAS.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should enter an expression for the  text formatting of that text box..

something like

```
=iif(Trim(Fields!State_Province.Value)="Arizona","0.0","0")
```

[image: Format]

[Format strings in SSRS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbxft59x.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for your support! Do you mean that I need to right-click on the state-province column and select text box properties?